# read on many real file descriptors

Tags: c, select, epoll

Working on a Linux (Ubuntu) application.  I need to read many files in a non-blocking fashion.  Unfortunately epoll doesn't support real file descriptor (file descriptor from file), it does support file descriptor that's network socket.  `select` does work on real file descriptors, but it has two drawbacks, 1) it's slow, linearly go through all the file descriptors that are set,  2) it's limited, it typically won't allow more than 1024 file descriptors.

I can change each file descriptors to be non-blocking and use non-blocking "read" to poll, but it's very expensive especially when there are a large number of file descriptors.

What are the options here?

Thanks.

**Update 1**
The use case here is to create some sort of file server, with many clients requesting for files, serve them in a non-blocking fashion.  Due to network side implementation (not standard TCP/IP stack), can't use sendfile().

Comment: Probably you looking for inotify.

Comment: @Dabo, my understanding of inotify is that it notifies when an event happens to a monitored file.  Don't think it will notify if data is ready for read, what do you think?

Comment: Why do you want to poll files?  Regular files shall always be ready  for reading and writing. If its the file server and needs to send the file to requesting clients why read files?

Comment: Note that [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) will always treat plain (disk) file descriptors as readable or writable.  (_File descriptors associated with regular files shall always select true for ready to read, ready to write, and error conditions._)

Comment: If blocking for disk I/O is acceptable, just read the real files immediately; if not, you *have* to use threads (which is what the AIO library does internally).

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple `select` calls combined with either threading or forking. This would reduce the number of `FD_ISSET` calls per `select` set.

*Perhaps you can provide more details about your use-case. It sounds like you are using `select` to monitor file changes, which doesn't work as you would expect with regular files. Perhaps you are simply looking for `flock`*

Comment: Updated the question with a short description on the application.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Asynchronous IO on Linux. The [relevant AIO manpages](http://linux.die.net/man/7/aio) (all in section 3) appear to have quite a bit of information. I think that [`aio_read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/aio_read) would probably be the most useful for you.

Here's some code that I believe you should be able to adapt for your usage:

```
...

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <aio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {
    struct aiocb *aio;
    connection_data *conn;
} cb_data;

void callback (union sigval u) {
    // recover file related data prior to freeing
    cb_data data = u.sival_ptr;
    int fd = data->aio->aio_fildes;
    uint8_t *buffer = data->aio->aio_buf;
    size_t len = data->aio->aio_nbytes;
    free (data->aio);

    // recover connection data pointer then free
    connection_data *conn = data->conn;
    free (data);

    ...

    // finish handling request

    ...

    return;
}

...

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    // initial setup

    ...

    // setup aio for optimal performance
    struct aioinit ainit = { 0 };
    // online background threads
    ainit.aio_threads = sysconf (_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN) * 4;
    // use defaults if using few core system
    ainit.aio_threads = (ainit.aio_threads > 20 ? ainit.aio_threads : 20)
    // set num to the maximum number of likely simultaneous requests
    ainit.aio_num = 4096;
    ainit.aio_idle_time = 5;

    aio_init (&ainit);

    ...

    // handle incoming requests
    int exit = 0;
    while (!exit) {

        ...

        // the [asynchronous] fun begins
        struct aiocb *cb = calloc (1, sizeof (struct aiocb));
        if (!cb)
            // handle OOM error
        cb->aio_fildes = file_fd;
        cb->aio_offset = 0; // assuming you want to send the entire file
        cb->aio_buf = malloc (file_len);
        if (!cb->aio_buf)
            // handle OOM error
        cb->aio_nbytes = file_len;
        // execute the callback in a separate thread
        cb->aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;

        cb_data *data = malloc (sizeof (cb_data));
        if (!data)
            // handle OOM error
        data->aio = cb; // so we can free() later
        // whatever you need to finish handling the request
        data->conn = connection_data;
        cb->aio_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = data;  // passed to callback
        cb->aio_sigevent.sigev_notify_function = callback;

        if ((err = aio_read (cb)))  // and you're done!
            // handle aio error

        // move on to next connection
    }

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

---

This will result in you no longer having to wait on files being read in your main thread. Of course, you can create more performant systems using AIO, but those are naturally likely to be more complex and this should work for a basic use case.

Comment: Thanks a lot  for the sample code! in the `callback` function, where is the chunk of data read from a file?  The application will need to do some sanitation of the data before sending it on to socket.

Comment: @codingFun the point of AIO is that it handles the IO portion for you. Once you're in the callback function, the file has already been read and is now sitting in `buffer`.

Comment: I created a compilable program based on your code snippet and it crashed. Any idea why?  Thanks.  The code is at  http://codepad.org/s8mTEHB3